# Applicative in Haskell for single variable

Tags: haskell

I recently started learning Haskell and encountered a problem with the idea of `Applicative`.

I need to make an implementation for

```
newtype MyTriple a = MyTriple (a,a,a) deriving Show
```

as `Applicative` instance.

I cannot really understand how exactly am i supposed to do that. As far as i know applicative is mostly used with more than one variable. In this particular example im not sure what should be in that part with `<*>` symbol.
Can someone please explain this to me (based on my example or not)?
If it is possible please dont provide a direct answer.

Comment: Applicatives basically allow youu to easily apply functions packed in your datatypes, to arguments that are packed in your datatype as well. In your case, your implementation of `<*>`  would be of type  `MyTripple (a -> b) -> MyTripple a -> MyTripple b`. Concretely, it would be a function for which the first argument would be a MyTriple containing three (possibly different) functions mapping from datatype `a` to `b`. The second argument would be a MyTripple containing values of type `a`, and the output would be the three functions applied to their respective functions, packed in `MyTriple`.

Comment: If you know what functors are, the equation `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` might help. `pure` could be called "pack", because it's basically a function putting a value into your "container" datatype. `fmap f x` executes "f" on the value encapsulated in x by your datatype, and ` pure f <*>  x`  first packes the function into your datatype before applying it with `<*>`.

Comment: oh... now i think i get it. Tbh now it seems kinda easy XD. Thank you very much

Comment: no problem, I don't think it's easy at all

Comment: in general no, but now i finally understood some points that i thought were impossible to comprehend and now it seems pretty easy and logical.

Comment: If you're doing this for yourself, and not for a class, I suggest you try to implement the `liftA2` method *instead of* the `(<*>)` method. To do this, you'll have to import `Control.Applicative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing an instance of a type class in Haskell, there are two things that can guide us to the correct implementation: types and type class laws.

### What does the type say?

One remarkable property of the type system used in Haskell (and some other functional languages as well) is that given a sufficiently polymorphic function
type, there are surprisingly few ways it can be implemented. The intuition is
that since a polymorphic function knows nothing about the types it operates on,
there are no interesting operations it can apply to values of these types.

The simplest example is a function of type `a -> a`. It must produce a value
of type `a` as its output; how can it come up with one? Since Haskell doesn't
provide a way to conjure a value of arbitrary type out of thin air<sup>1</sup>,
the function must use its input value of type `a`. What can it do with it? Since
it's a value of an arbitrary type, the answer is "nothing" - it can only return
it as its result. Thus, the only reasonable function of type `a -> a` is the
identity function. A more thorough explanation of this idea and further examples can be found in a [famous paper by P. Wadler](https://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen5533/fall11/reading/free.pdf).

Let's go back to the example at hand. The types of `pure` and `<*>` in the
`Applicative` instance for `MyTriple` are

```
pure  :: a -> MyTriple a
(<*>) :: MyTriple (a -> b) <*> MyTriple a -> MyTriple b
```

In `pure`, to construct `MyTriple a`, we need a triple of values of type `a`.
Since we are given one value of type `a` and we have no way of producing any
other (just like in the `a -> a` function), the only way to implement it is as

```
pure x = MyTriple (x, x, x)
```

Operator `<*>` is more interesting. In this case:

```
MyTriple (f, g, h) <*> MyTriple (x, y, z) = ...
-- f, g, h :: a -> b
-- x, y, z :: a
```

we are given three functions of type `a -> b` and three values of type `a`.
To construct `MyTriple b`, we need three values of type `b`. The only way
to get our hands on the value of type `b` is to apply one of `f`, `g`, `h` to
one of `x`, `y`, `z`. There is no unique way to do this; we can pair up
the functions and their arguments in an arbitrary fashion.
It follows that all the possible implementations of `<*>` for `MyTriple` are of the form

```
MyTriple (f1, f2, f3) <*> MyTriple (x1, x1, x3) = MyTriple (fi xp, fj xq, fk xr)
```

for some values of `i`, `j`, `k` and `p`, `q`, `r` between 1 and 3.
From the point of view of the type system, all these are correct.
In general, there may be multiple valid instances of applicative functor for a given type (e.g. list has two: the [regular one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1121) and [ZipList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList)),
so it's not necessarily a problem. That being said, there is one more thing we
need to consider.

### Applicative functor laws

The [applicative functor laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) are the following rules:

- **Identity**: `pure id <*> v = v`
- **Composition**: `pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)`
- **Homomorphism**: `pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)`
- **Interchange**: `u <*> pure y = pure ($y) <*> u`

A valid instance of the applicative functor must satisfy all these equations.
Note that it is **not** enforced by the compiler - this responsibility lies with the programmer.

At this point, we need to figure out what additional constraints do the applicative functor laws put on the implementation of operator `<*>` for
`MyTriple`.
Let's start with the **Identity**. Using our definitions of `pure` and `<*>`, the
identity law requires that

```
MyTriple (x1, x1, x3) = MyTriple (id xp, id xq, id xr) = MyTriple (xp, xq, xr)
```

The only way for this to hold for all possible values of `x`'s is
if `p = 1`, `q = 2` and `r = 3`. This narrows down the set of possible definitions
of `<*>` to

```
MyTriple (f1, f2, f3) <*> MyTriple (x1, x1, x3) = MyTriple (fi x1, fj x2, fk x3)
```

so the components of the right argument of `<*>` cannot be permuted.

What about the left argument? The answer to that question is given by the **interchange** law. We have

```
MyTriple (f1, f2, f3) <*> pure x = MyTriple (fi x, fj x, fk x)
```

and by the interchange law this must be equal to

```
pure ($x) <*> MyTriple (f1, f2, f3) = MyTriple (fp x, fq x, fr x)
```

since in this case `f` functions assume the role of arguments of `$x`, that is
`($x) f = f x`. Combining these two, we see that

```
MyTriple (fi x, fj x, fk x) = MyTriple (fp x, fq x, fr x)
```

and again, the only way for this to hold regardless of `f`'s and `x` is if `i = p`, `j = q` and `k = r`, so `i = 1`, `j = 2`, `k = 3`. The final version of operator `<*>`, the only one satisfying the applicative functor laws<sup>2</sup>,
is thus the simplest and most natural one:

```
MyTriple (f1, f2, f3) <*> MyTriple (x1, x1, x3) = MyTriple (f1 x1, f2 x2, f3 x3)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Apart from `undefined` & co.

<sup>2</sup> Strictly speaking, we need to check the remaining two laws
(**composition** and **homomorphism**) before we are done

Answer (score 3):

I think in terms of `liftA2` rather than `(<*>)`. `(<*>)` is lifted function application

```
(<*>) = liftA2 ($)
```

For your type, the applicative performs "element-wise" lifting, meaning n-th element in your result is the combination of the incoming n-th element

```
type V3 :: Type -> Type
data V3 a = V3 a a a
  deriving
  stock Functor

instance Applicative V3 where
 pure :: forall a. a -> V3 a
 pure a = V3 a a a

 liftA2 :: forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> (V3 a -> V3 b -> V3 c)
 liftA2 (·) (V3 a1 a2 a3)
            (V3 b1 b2 b3)
          = (V3 c1 c2 c3)
  where

  c1, c2, c3 :: c
  c1 = a1 · b1
  c2 = a2 · b2
  c3 = a3 · b3
```

Lists of a given length (vectors) are isomorphic to functions

```
Vec 0 a = (Void  -> a)
Vec 1 a = (()    -> a)
Vec 2 a = (Bool  -> a)
Vec 3 a = (Fin3  -> a)
..
Vec n a = (Fin n -> a)
```

and their applicative instance follows the element-wise function definition. Functors like `MyTriple` and others isomorphic to functions `(.. ->)` are called [`Representable` functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html).

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
 pure :: b -> (a -> b)
 pure = const

 liftA2 :: (b1 -> b2 -> b3) -> ((a->b1) -> (a->b2) -> (a->b3))
 (liftA2 (·) bs1 bs2) a = 
   bs1 a · bs2 a
```

Verify that `(->) Fin3` is isomorphic to `V3`/`MyTriple` with the same `Applicative` instance.

Consider what happens when `(·)` is instantiated with `($)`.

---

With base 4.17 you can use `Generically1` (from `GHC.Generics`) to derive `Applicative`:

```
type V3 :: Type -> Type
data V3 a = V3 a a a
  deriving
  stock (Functor, Generic1)

  deriving Applicative
  via Generically1 V3
```

---

You can [derive `Applicative` and `Monad`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) for any Representable functor via [`Co V3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Co)

```
type V3 :: Type -> Type
data V3 a = V3 a a a
 deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
 via Co V3

instance Distributive V3 where
 distribute :: Functor f => f (V3 a) -> V3 (f a)
 distribute = distributeRep

type Fin3 :: Type
data Fin3 = Fin0 | Fin1 | Fin2

instance Representable V3 where
 type Rep V3 = Fin3

 index :: V3 a -> (Fin3 -> a)
 index (V3 a b c) = \case
  Fin0 -> a
  Fin1 -> b
  Fin2 -> c

 tabulate :: (Fin3 -> a) -> V3 a
 tabulate make = V3 (make Fin0) (make Fin1) (make Fin2)
```

We would derive `Distributive` if it weren't for "role" problems, i.e. we cannot coerce under the argument of the functor `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're not having problem with `pure`.

You can play around with `MyTriple` and `<*>` in GHCi to get a better sense for what you're supposed to do. For example, you can ask about the type of `<*>` if you constrain the return type to `MyTriple _`:

```
*Q65326400> :t (<*>) :: _ -> _ -> MyTriple _

<interactive>:1:10: error:
    * Found type wildcard `_' standing for `MyTriple (a1 -> w1)'
      Where: `a1', `w1' are rigid type variables bound by
               the inferred type of
                 <expression> :: MyTriple (a1 -> w1) -> MyTriple a1 -> MyTriple w1
               at <interactive>:1:10-29
      To use the inferred type, enable PartialTypeSignatures
    * In an expression type signature: _ -> _ -> MyTriple _
      In the expression: (<*>) :: _ -> _ -> MyTriple _

...
```

(More, similar, error messages follow...)

This looks scary, but it actually tells you what the involved types are supposed to be:

```
MyTriple (a1 -> w1) -> MyTriple a1 -> MyTriple w1
```

or, if we translate to more 'friendly' type variables:

```
MyTriple (a -> b) -> MyTriple a -> MyTriple b
```

So, as @Nearoo has pointed out in the comments, the left-hand side of `<*>` should be a `MyTriple` value that contains functions of the type `a -> b`. These can be three different functions, but they must have compatible types.

The right-hand side should be a `MyTriple a`, and the return value a `MyTriple b`.

You could, for example, implement an `Applicative` instance that behaves like this:

```
*Q65326400> MyTriple (null, odd . length, elem 'f') <*> MyTriple ("foo", "bar", "baz")
MyTriple (False,True,False)
```

The left-hand side is a `MyTriple (String -> Bool)` value, and the right-hand side is a `MyTriple String`.

This isn't the only possible `Applicative` instance. I can easily think of a dozen more instances, but they probably wouldn't all be lawful.

The next step, once you've figured out how to implement an instance, is to convince yourself (and possibly others) that the instance obeys the [applicative functor laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html). That's going to rule out some of those technically possible instances.

Comment: There's exactly one lawful instance. You can show that with parametricity, the identity law, and the interchange law.